# ArcMap Euclidean distance error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, error-999999

I am trying to do a Euclidean distance analysis on my polyline shapefile. When I try to put the cell size as default when trying a Euclidean distance together with a given processing extent everything seems to work but the cells are too big to be process later with my other layers on weighted overlay. When I tried to put my cell size together with a given processing extent I get an error 99999. I already checked my projections and they are on the right WGS 1984 projection. I also tried giving the output path a different folder other than .gdb but it still doesn't work.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the settings that works but has a big cell size.]

[image: Here is a screenshot of the settings thats having ERROR 99999]

Comment: Why not try and set the cell size to one of your overlay rasters in the environment settings section?

Comment: thats what I was trying to do. I just tried to input the cell size manually since I thought basing the cell size from other layers is the issue, which clearly isn't. Anything I put other than 0.00176355 that is being given by defalut by the tool seems to not run